# MYSQL get spacific table fields counts

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I have the following 2 tables.

First is: `idea_box`

[image]

Second is: `idea_box_voting`

[image]

Now I want result something like this, based on `0 and 1 count`from thumbs field.

[image]

I have never created sql query like this one so I am hoping that someone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.idea_id, a.property_id, a.the_idea, a.user_id, a.added_date, a.status, 
       SUM(b.thumbs = 1) AS up, SUM(b.thumbs = 0) AS down
FROM idea_box a 
LEFT JOIN idea_box_voting b ON a.idea_id = b.idea_id 
GROUP BY a.idea_id;
```

Comment: Excellent thumbs up for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ib.*,
       SUM(ibv.thumbs=1) as UP,
       SUM(ibv.thumbs=0) as DOWN 
FROM idea_box ib LEFT JOIN
     idea_box_voting ibv on ib.idea_id=ibv.idea_id
GROUP BY ib.idea_id
```

An example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9c57/7).

Comment: Why are you added all fields in group by clause? Have any meaning for that?

Comment: @Sadikhasan: Not needed for mysql though. Just making sure !! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT t1.*,sum(t2.thumbs=1) as up,sum(t2.thumbs=0) as down  FROM table1 as t1 left join table2 as t2 using(idea_id) group by t1.idea_id;